# Firefox resolution not proportional

Tags: linux-mint, kde, firefox

I've just installed Linux Mint 17.2 (Raffaela) KDE. I am experiencing a strange problem with Firefox though: The Firefox controls (toolbar, bookmarks, tabs, etc.) in Firefox look huge compared to the rest of the KDE environment, and I haven't found a way to change that. Also, the page rendering looks weird, but at least that's changeable using the zoom functionality of Firefox. I have a suspicion that it's related to the fact that I'm using the Nvidia proprietary driver (nouveau does not work with my graphics card, which is a known issue). Does anybody know how I can fix that?

I've attached a screenshot which illustrates the issue.

Thanks!

[image: Firefox in Linux Mint]

Comment: What value do you have for a `layout.css.dpi` option in about:config?

Comment: Just checked, it's the default value -1. I've tried changing it, but I didn't see anything different.

Comment: check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox_tweaks#Configure_the_DPI_value also

Comment: Thanks for the link, I managed to fix the issue using this Plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autohidpi/